# Midnight Command for selecting multiple files

Tags: mc

I'm using developer mode of windows for using mc. I know for selecting multiple files for unix system Insert key is used. But for windows how I will select multiple files.

Comment: <Insert> doesn't work for you?

Comment: No. It did't work for me.

Comment: Try [Ctrl]+[t].